# Warning: unmatched pseudo-class :host-context

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, sass

I just upgraded to Angular 12, and now I'm seeing this warning when I run my build:

```
Warning: 52 rules skipped due to selector errors:
    :host-context() -> unmatched pseudo-class :host-context
    ...
```

Everything compiles and runs as expected. Is there any way to remove these warnings?

Comment: are you using mdbootstrap?  there are some weird things going on right now with some of the classes importing properly with ivy.  its really something that you should should just fix - even if its super painful.  and according to the last site we did it took about 45 minutes and we were done.

Comment: @chrisburd I'm not using mdbootstrap :(

Comment: you might want to just remove your node_modules folder and run npm install

Comment: @chrisburd I've tried this, I get the same results.

Comment: you have to post more than this - I can't help you if you don't, because you posted one thing and I don't even know what gave the error.  I am happy to try and help you though.

Comment: I experience the same problem. Did you find a solution on it ?